# TextInputLayout maintain hint color when losing focus

Tags: android, focus, android-textinputlayout, hint, android-textinputedittext

I have a TextInputLayout with a TextInputEditText inside it. Now, I have it with the hint color on grey when nothing is typed yet and the hint color becomes blue once the user types on it and the hint gets smaller and moves upper (the normal animation). The problem is that once I tap on another edittext, the hint of the first one becomes grey again, and I want it to keep being blue.

This is my code:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/textInputLayoutAppearance">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:hint="@string/str_usuario"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and the style:

```
<style name="textInputLayoutAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the hint color as below -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/parent_to_view_margin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/til_email">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```